# После создания контроллера и вью чере Gii по адресу получаю 404 ошибку. Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, controller, gii

С помощью генератора кода GII создал новый контроллер и вью. Все стандартно.

контроллер:

```
namespace app\controllers;

    class ClientInfoController extends \yii\web\Controller
    {
        public function actionIndex()
        {
            return $this->render('index');
        }

    }
```

вью:

```
<?php
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
?>
<h1>client-info/index</h1>

<p>
    You may change the content of this page by modifying
    the file <code><?= __FILE__; ?></code>.
</p>
```

правила:

```
'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'gii'=>'gii/index',
                'user'=>'user/user/index',
            ],
        ],
```

при переходе на http://sitename/clientinfo попадаю на страницу с 404 ошибкой.
Все остальные контроллеры работают правильно. В файл с контроллером попадаю, во всяком случае если сделать синтаксическую ошибку , дебагер ругается на правильный файл.
В чем может быть причина?

Comment: у меня такая же ерунда. уже третий день ищу ответ. у меня все это добро запускается через openserver. надо как то настроить конфигурацию apache (если бы еще знать как :( )

Comment: @Виталий у меня просто класс с большой буквы назывался, по-этому не работало